# LaTeXTools + Sublime Text 3 does not compile (after installing Yosemite public beta)

Tags: macos, latex, sublimetext3, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

I have been using `LaTeXTools` + Sublime Text 3 for a while, and they work fine. After installing the public beta of Yosemite, Sublime Text + `LaTeXTools` stops working: the `build` command brings up output window showing NO errors:

```
Compiling /Users/.../sometexfile.tex

TraditionalBuilder: Invoking latexmk... done.

No errors. Warnings:
```

It generates `.aux` and `.fdb_latexmk` files, but not others, in particular not the PDF.

Fortunately TexShop works fine, and if I compile with TexShop to generate a PDF, the forward/backward sync still works in Sublime Text.

I wonder is there any fix?

Comment: Hi - just had same problem. Deleted existing temporary files (aux, out, etc.) and reran the build - PDF was regenerated.

Comment: For me the issue still stands. I have to keep deleting tomporary files (very annoying). Have set the builder from traditional to simple as suggested by jiehanzheng, but it does not help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click Sublime Text on menu bar, and then navigate to Preferences > Package Settings > LaTeXTools > Settings - User.

On around line 91, change builder from "traditional" to "simple".

See: https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/401